# compiling libcurl 7.61.1 from source on Windows 10

Tags: c++, libcurl

I'm working on an existing C++ project. We include libcurl as a static library, which we build from source. I'm trying to upgrade us from version 7.38.0 to version 7.61.1.

I downloaded `curl-7.61.1.zip` from here: https://curl.haxx.se/download/.

I made no modifications to the source and did not run any scripts that came with curl 7.61.1.

We have an existing VS solution we used for compiling curl 7.38.0, so I started from that and modified as needed for the new files in curl 7.61.1.

Everything compiled fine, however, when I try to link the compiled result into my project, I get the following errors:

```
1>libcurl.lib(schannel.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CertOpenStore referenced in function schannel_connect_step1
1>libcurl.lib(schannel_verify.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_CertOpenStore
1>libcurl.lib(schannel.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CertCloseStore referenced in function schannel_connect_step1
1>libcurl.lib(schannel_verify.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_CertCloseStore
1>libcurl.lib(schannel.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CertFindCertificateInStore referenced in function schannel_connect_step1
1>libcurl.lib(schannel.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CertFreeCertificateContext referenced in function pkp_pin_peer_pubkey
1>libcurl.lib(schannel_verify.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_CertFreeCertificateContext
1>libcurl.lib(schannel.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol  __imp_CryptStringToBinaryA referenced in function schannel_connect_step1
1>libcurl.lib(schannel_verify.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CertAddCertificateContextToStore referenced in function add_certs_to_store
1>libcurl.lib(schannel_verify.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CertGetNameStringA referenced in function verify_host
1>libcurl.lib(schannel_verify.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CryptQueryObject referenced in function add_certs_to_store
1>libcurl.lib(schannel_verify.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CertCreateCertificateChainEngine referenced in function verify_certificate
1>libcurl.lib(schannel_verify.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CertFreeCertificateChainEngine referenced in function verify_certificate
1>libcurl.lib(schannel_verify.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CertGetCertificateChain referenced in function verify_certificate
1>libcurl.lib(schannel_verify.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CertFreeCertificateChain referenced in function verify_certificate
1>C:\Users\CoffeeTableEspresso\project\win64-vs15\debug-mt\executable.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 12 unresolved externals
```

Has anyone run into similar issues before? Please let me know if I need to edit this with more info as well.

Comment: Most likely the library now uses functions from a [Windows library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/) that it didn't before, so you must link against it. The old projects miss this dependency.

Comment: You should probably make sure that you build with the same TLS backend as you did before, to reduce the number of issues you might see in the upgrade process.

Comment: @DanielStenberg if only I knew _how_ we built it before...

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider you were completely right, linking against `crypt32.lib` solved this for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Peter mentioned in a comment, I needed to link against windows libraries.  In this case, linking against `crypt32.lib` solved the issue for me.